# UINavigationBar and UITabBar tint to match UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am setting the `barTintColor` of `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. I want my `UIView`'s background to be the exact same color so that the nav bar and tab bar appear invisible. However, I can't get the colors to match.

Here is the background set to the exact same color as the navigation bar. 
[image]

Here is how I'm adjusting the color of the bars:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.78 green:0.05 blue:0.2 alpha:1]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your steps almost exactly and was able to match the colors.

[image]

The main difference was I set the **barTintColor:** directly to it's root view's background color.

Here is my code:

```
 itemsViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemsViewController];


navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = itemsViewController.view.backgroundColor;
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

So I'm going to say that your issue is that you are not setting the right **barTintColor:** because your RGB color values are incorrect. I'd focus your efforts there.

Answer (score -1):

You can get rid of this by only setting up:

```
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Thus whenever you give your `UIView` the same color that you have given to your navigation bar, it will matches.

Setting `translucent` to `NO` is the real solution.